# Filtering input with sed (regex)

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed

I'm having an issue with sed not returning what I expect when using a regex pattern to clean up some output from a mysql query.

```
mysql -uroot -p -e 'SELECT `path` FROM db.media_gallery' | sed -n -r 's/[^\/]+([^\s]+).*/\1/p'
```

The query returns a bunch of rows such as these:

```
| /media/M/W/lmt_MWS04_8.png    |
| /media/M/W/lmt_MWS02_11.png   |
```

When I pipe this through the sed command listed above, it returns this:

```
//M/W/lmt_MWS04_8.png
//M/W/lmt_MWS02_11.png
```

Where did "media" go? Why does it randomly remove a part of my string?

Does anyone know how to fix my regex?

Comment: "media" goes away because it is matched by the `[^\/]+` part of your regex, which isn't included in your output. We can't fix your regex unless we know what you were trying to do. Are you trying to trim whitespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for sed, the real problem is you're using mysql's prettified output that's intended for human rather than automated consumption. This is a simple task that mysql is more than capable of.

```
mysql -N -s -r -uroot -p -e 'SELECT `path` FROM db.media_gallery'
```

will return:

```
/media/M/W/lmt_MWS04_8.png
/media/M/W/lmt_MWS02_11.png
```

from 'man mysql':

```
--skip-column-names, -N
--silent, -s
--raw, -r
```

Answer (score 0):

The "media" matched "[^/]+" so it was replaced by the stuff in the parentheses.  If you want it, you need to open the parentheses before that regex clause.